# Celery - How to route task to local worker only

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have a Django view where a user can upload a file to process.

I'd like to hand off the processing to a celery task but I need to give the task a path to the file.

The problem is I have 3 servers running the Django app and the same three servers running celery workers.

Is there a way I can tell Celery I only want the task to run on a worker that's on the same server where the file was uploaded?

(Or is there a way better way to do this?  I don't have any shared locations all three servers can see files.)

Comment: you can create a model like MyTask and save the path to the file into the DB. Instead of passing file path to the task, you will pass the ID of the task. When the task will be triggered you will get MyTask instance and corresponding path. It will work fine because you have one DB across all the servers.

Comment: That's fine for the file path, but the file actually exists on only the one server right.  Ultimately I need the task to access the file.

Comment: Yes. It still will work. Imagine you save the path to the file into the DB. Celery worker receives the task ID, extracts path and try to run the task. If file does not exist on this specific server then task fails and it will be sent to another worker on another server. One more notice - in Celery tutotrials there is advice not the pass variables which can be changed into the task!

Comment: What will make it automatically fail to another worker/server?  Is that a setting?  My normal tasks just fail once when they fail.

Comment: you have message broker. As I understand, if task fails then it is "redirected" to another worker. And it is written everywhere it does not matter on which server the worker is located. However, I am also looking for a good tutorial which explains everything in details. Hope my answer helps somehow!